# search engine based on CSV files

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am newbie  in NLP, Recently I am doing price comparison tool that selecting information need of user, the whole process behind of the tool is looking up for the product category of information need first and then get most similar products under this category. my datasets are clean, structured, stored in CSV files with attributes including "id", "retailer","product category", "product name","price_unit","price","quantity" 
in my product category list, some product category already contains the key word of products ("ASDA Chosen by Kids Cute and Juicy Apples" is under "Apples, pears rhunarb"). 
 but there are some exceptions such as  "selection lemon" and "selection lime" are under "citrus fruits" category

so I need to match input query(input product name by user) and product category first, but  how to identify classification / product category of a input product  given by user  is not sure now for me, i got advice like using inverted index.
can anyone give me more advice of this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Please upvote my answer or mark it as correct if it is the case. Tx!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is item-item recommendation. Have a look at [item-item collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item-item_collaborative_filtering). Since you have keywords associated with each item. You could also dive into cosin-similarily. You might also be interested in [graph based recommender engine techniques](https://markorodriguez.com/2011/09/22/a-graph-based-movie-recommender-engine/)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, according to your recommendation, I checked item-item collaborative filtering out, it seems to be suitable for doing recommender engine you mentioned via comparing the similarity between items. what i am doing now is trying to find out what product categories of users input product are. my datasets come from different  merchants like tesco, supervalu, morrisons, so they have their own category name for product

Comment: (for instance: tesco put apples and bananas those products under "fresh fruit" category, while asad categorizes "selection apples","selection banans" as  "apples, bananas" ), so if user want to search "apples", for the case of asad supermarket, i could use keywords matching, for tesco scenairo, i might be using semantic similarity  to check how similar two phrase senses are. once i collect product categories which matching to this products, i could use string similarity to matching product name(descriptions) under these product categories, which would dramatically reduce workloads,memory

Comment: because this is a  price comparison tool that the results will show all most relevant products across multiple merchants. if i am using these two methods together, i am not sure how to apply them properly. i have ever thought directly matching product name, good point is that gives you most relevant results, but it took long time to run through all data and memory space, in fact, most of product you know in datasets are not relevant at all to what you want, so it only waste of time.

Comment: by the way, i am using Jaccard similarity coefficient with shingling and cosine similarity to matching product name or say product description